# How to require different permissions in annotation depending on Android version

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have a function in a custom library that requires the `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` and `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` permissions. Starting with Android 12, I can't just rely on adding them to the manifest XML - runtime checks are also required then.

I added the `RequiresPermission` annotation to my function, like this:

```
@RequiresPermission(allOf = [Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT])
fun myFunction()
```

However, I get this warning:

> Field requires API level 31 (current min is 28): android.Manifest.permission#BLUETOOTH_SCAN

I set the min SDK version to 28 on purpose. But now I am stuck. for Android 12 and newer, I need the annotation to emphasize that callers check for those permissions (in other words, I want there to be a warning if callers use my function without a permission check). for Android 11 and older, the annotation must not be present? How do I solve this? I know that `RequiresPermission` has a `conditional` argument, but I do not know how to use this for this purpose. I tried to instead use `BLUETOOTH` and `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permissions in the annotation, but Android Studio still complains that the Bluetooth APIs that are internally used in the function need to be surrounded by permission checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could annotate android version like the following (for example only, this is a different permission request)

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    @RequiresPermission(allOf = {Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS})
```

Although I find it easier to read and debug later by having all versions call the request permission function then return early if the version is too low

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
  return
}
//continue to ask for permission
```

Comment: @RequiresApi would restrict that API to that level and above, right? If I want to permit usage of the API on Android 9 through 12, I have no choice but to use runtime checks and cannot use the annotation?

Comment: Yes, but you cannot require permissions for permissions that do not exist for the lower APIs.  This is the reason I suggest requesting/verifying the permission exists in a permission function.  In the permission function, if the Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is less than the required Build return as permission accepted. If Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= the required Build verify/ask for permission.

Comment: Alright, I will have to do it that way then, thanks.